# How to create a Grouped Radial Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, visualization

I have a data like as below in a csv file, how I can create a Grouped Radial Bar Chart in R as available in below link:

[sample chart link](http://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0a9bf537a64a55ab1fe8)

image:[image]

data:

Candidate Type,Exp-Fresher,2-4 Years,5-7 Years,8-10 Years,11-15 Years
Java Developers,44,27,21,38,10                                           Business Analyst,40,32,14,24,6
UI Designers,22,18,15,10,2
DB Specialists,41,35,29,16,7
ETL Developers,39,25,12,7,3
Testers,23,18,15,12,5

Comment: and how did your first attempt go?

Answer (score 0):

As an indication on how you might start, here's an example, based on the data you provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(df[,1]), y=as.numeric(df[,2]))) + coord_polar() + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=as.numeric(df[,2]))
```

where

```
> df
    Candidate.Type Exp.Fresher X2.4.Years X5.7.Years X8.10.Years X11.15.Years
1 Java Developers           44         27         21          38           10
2 Business Analyst          40         32         14          24            6
3 UI Designers              22         18         15          10            2
4 DB Specialists            41         35         29          16            7
5 ETL Developers            39         25         12           7            3
6 Testers                   23         18         15          12            5
```

[image]

In this image only the first category, "Exp.Fresher" is plotted. The color codes, the captions, the number of categories and many other aspects can be improved or expanded as required. This is just an example to show how a radial bar chart can be prepared using the `ggplot2` package in `R`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for Grouped radial bar chart..if i give like ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(as.character(df[,1])),
              y=factor(as.numeric(df[,2:5])) + coord_polar()+
            geom_bar(stat="identity",fill=factor(df[,2]))  then it shows below error:
Error in factor(as.numeric(df[, 2:5])) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'